# Correct workflow to online validate non-consumable in-app purchase receipts on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

What is the correct workflow to online validate the in-app purchase of non-consumable IAPs on iOS?

While I found a lot of information about in-app purchases in general I found no details on how to actually perform online validation.

**Is the following workflow correct and complete or am I missing something?**

**General setup:**

- iOS app starts purchase by adding an `SKPaymentQueue` to the payment queue
- iOS calls `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` with `transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` when purchase is complete
- At this time the app receipt has already been updated and the purchase of the non-consumable item was added.
- The receipt data and `transaction.transactionIdentifier` are send via HTTP POST to my own web service
- The web service POSTs the data to Apples `/verifyReceipt` endpoint
- Apples server response with an error if the receipt is invalid or with detailed JSON data if receipt is valid
- The JSON Data received from Apple includes information about all prior non-consumable and subscription purchases AND the current consumable purchase.
- The information about the consumable purchase can be identified by the `product_id` field or by using the `transaction.transactionIdentifier`
- The web service adds the purchase to the current user account and/or sends back an valid/invalid response to the iOS app.
- If necessary (when the purchase is not stored/handled online) the iOS app can handle the purchase (add coins, or whatever)
- The transaction is closed using `[queue finishTransaction:transaction]`

**Additional Observations:**

- The receipt includes information about all prior non-consumable and subscription purchases AND the current/last consumable purchase.
- The information about the current consumable purchase is available until the next purchase (no matter if consumable, non-consumable or subscription).
- Restarting the app does not destroy the information about the current consumable purchase
- When the app is deleted and re-installed the receipt is empty / does not exist. After restoring previous purchases the receipt only includes information about non-consumable and subscription purchases. No information about non-consumable purchases is restored (no surprise)

**Conclusion:**

- If (for some reason) the receipt cannot send be to the web service (server down, no connection, etc.), this can be retry later. The purchase data will be available within the receipt until the next purchase.
- To be able to access the receipt data even after the next purchase one has to implement a custom storage method (e.g. save receipt data to file).
- This way the user can be informed about outstanding validations and a retry option can be offered.

**Is this a complete and valid workflow to validate consumable in-app purchases online or am I missing some special cases?**

Comment: Step 3 is in the wrong place.  Do not call `finishTransaction` until you have successfully verified the receipt and persisted the purchase. That way if your server is unavailable and you can not verify the receipt then the transaction will be presented again to your payment queue observer when the app starts next time. I already explained this to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594630/ios-in-app-purchase-receipt-validation-what-happens-if-server-is-down/52598296#52598296)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Some discussions in the Apple Dev Forums suggest to avoid unfinished transactions since this might lead to strange and unexpected behavior of the payment queue. It would be better to store the receipt manually and retry later. Are there any disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: Yes,  because it can result in the user not getting what they paid for.  In the case of an auto-renewing or non-consumable they can always use the "restore" button so it isn't too bad, but for a consumable purchase you are telling Apple that you have given them what they paid for but you haven't; If your app then doesn't process the transaction correctly the purchase is lost as far as the user can tell.  If you are correctly instantiating your payment queue observer when the app launches then there is no problem with leaving the transaction unfinished.